# Flutter body background

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const Background({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

I get this errors. Can someone help?

- The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
- With null safety, use the 'required' keyword, not the '@required' annotation.
  Try removing the '@'.

Answer (score 1):

You are using named constructor and parameters are optional by default, You can include required before Key or make it nullable.

On null-safety `@required` has been changed to `required`

```dart
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const Background({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);
}
```

More about [using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors) and [`StatelessWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html).

And [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: after removing @ i get this error in widget build : The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.

Comment: use like `Key? key` to make key nullable

Comment: Glad to help, you can check those link to understand the concept in details.